# Mongodb multikey index and $all in queries

Tags: index, mongodb

I have such structure of documents in my `products` collection:

```
{
  title: 'Samsung Galaxy S III',
  category_id: ObjectId("50bcc2f0b910a6c1936a4424"),
  properties: [
    {
      title: 'OS',
      value: 'Android'
    },
    {
      title: 'Display',
      value: '4.8"'
    }
  ]
}
```

Also I've created multikey index: `{category_id: 1, 'properties.value': 1, 'properties.title': 1}`

What happens when I do query with $all? How it works? Example:

```
{
  category_id: ObjectId("50bcc2f0b910a6c1936a4424"),
  properties: {
    $all: [
      {
        $elemMatch: {
          title: 'OS',
          value: 'Android'
        }
      },
      {
        $elemMatch: {
          title: 'Display',
          value: '4.8"'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does it find elements in index by first $elemMatch and then iterate over all found element to ensure second $elemMatch?

For my test collection with 2 androids and 1 ios `explain()` returns:

```
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor category_id_1_properties.title_1_properties.value_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2,
        "nscanned" : 2,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "category_id" : [
                    [
                            ObjectId("50bcc2f0b910a6c1936a4424"),
                            ObjectId("50bcc2f0b910a6c1936a4424")
                    ]
            ],
            "properties.title" : [
                    [
                            "OS",
                            "OS"
                    ]
            ],
            "properties.value" : [
                    [
                            "Android",
                            "Android"
                    ]
            ]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, not sure if you have altered the question or not since posted, but contrary to one of the answers, this is not doing a full collection scan, it is using an index, as evidenced by the `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor` in the explain output.

As for your question - you are asking about the `$all` operator, but I think your issue here is that you are using the `$elemMatch` operator incorrectly.  When you do:

```
$elemMatch: {
          title: 'OS',
          value: 'Android'
        }
```

Or similar, you are running `$elemMatch` against a document, not an array, which is how it is intended.  Hence the explain shows the bounds on the index as specific values of just `OS` and `Android` on `properties.title` and `properties.value` respectively rather than what you probably wanted, which I think is to only return if all the various properties are present in the array.

Try without `$elemMatch`:

```
{
  category_id: ObjectId("50bcc2f0b910a6c1936a4424"),
  properties: {
    $all: [
      {
          title: 'OS',
          value: 'Android'
      },
      {
          title: 'Display',
          value: '4.8"'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
But in your case dataset is too small for effective using of index. So MongoDB decided to use full collection scan.

Comment: It use index at least for one $elemMatch. See, I've added "indexBounds". Does it decided to scan all found elements for second $elemMatch?

Comment: There are a few subquestions in the original post.  Could you indicate here which one do you answer?  Thanks in advance.